flet. Постоянно ловлю исключение когда закрываю вкладку или обновляю страницу
Вот самый простой код:
import flet as ft
from flet import Page, Text

def main(page: Page):
    page.title = "Hello, Flet!"
    page.add(Text("Hello, Flet!"))

ft.app(target=main)


Запускаю приложение как web:
flet run .\minimal.py --web -p 4488
И как только я закрываю вкладку или обновляю страницу(F5), сразу же получаю исключение:
Exception in callback _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)
handle: <Handle _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 162, in _call_connection_lost
    self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

После этого всё работает, пока не понял есть ли вред.
Но выглядит пугающе.
Это нормально?
С этим надо что то делать?

Не могу у себя повторить

Какая версия flet?

@DmitriGalkin
Ну как то так:
flet                  0.22.1
flet-core             0.22.1
flet-runtime          0.22.1
